# Why ther is an Unhandled Exception Error in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HelloWorld
{
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int a, b, c;
 Console.WriteLine("give a:");
 a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine("give b:");
 b=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  
  c=a+b;
  Console.WriteLine("c={0}",c);
} 
}
}
```

The error is this :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00003] in <9f0df102fe6e4cfea29d2e46f585d8a5>:0 
  at HelloWorld.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00011] in <47cc63d67af642a680e3be47ee0a2658>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00003] in <9f0df102fe6e4cfea29d2e46f585d8a5>:0 
  at HelloWorld.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00011] in <47cc63d67af642a680e3be47ee0a2658>:0
```

Why does this error appear?

I'm using a mobile compiler.

Is it because there are 2 inputs and the mobile compiler can't handle more than one input?

Or is it an error in the code?

Comment: Is this error stopping you from compiling the program, or does it occurs at some point during compiling (after you write something etc)?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` is returning null because it has reached the end of input. How are you running your app?

Comment: aca- After i run the program(output)

Comment: Matthew Watson- I'm running on Android

Comment: What are the values you provide for `a` and `b`?

Comment: Etheraex- I couldn't provide any value, when i clicked run, this output appears

Comment: Are you sure that the code is as shown and that you haven't got a space in `args` making it `arg s`? Or maybe try `arg` instead of `args`

Comment: ChrisBD - I can provide screenshot if you want

Comment: ChrisBD- Thank you i put arg, it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly a conundrum. Online compilers can be a bit iffy.
I've just tried the following code on [TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php)

```
/* Online C# Compiler and Editor */
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            Console.WriteLine("give a:");
            a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("give b:");
            b=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  
            c=a+b;
            Console.WriteLine("c={0}",c);
        } 
    }
}
```

And it works:

Output:

```
give a:
1
give b:
2
c=3
```

**edit**

Inclusion of my remark and thinking behind it to the original question:

Your original error message:

> Parameter name: s
> at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00003] in <9f0df102fe6e4cfea29d2e46f585d8a5>:0
> at HelloWorld.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00011] in <47cc63d67af642a680e3be47ee0a2658>:0

indicates that there is a parameter called `s`. Perhaps the online compiler that you used recognises `arg` but not `args` and so sees the `s` as a parameter of an unknown type.
Try `arg` instead of `args`